# Facebook window.fbAsyncInit not firing in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to integrate my Chrome extension with Facebook but I can't make the fbAsyncInit to execute.

This is what I have on the html of my extension (editPage.html):

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"> </div> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/initializeFacebook.js"></script>
  ....
 </body>
```

I open this html by calling:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  url : chrome.extension.getURL('editPage.html'),
    selected : true
}, function(tab) {
});
```

This is whats inside initializeFacebook.js (taken from this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

```
 ( function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
console.log('lala');
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
    appId : 'XXXX', 
    status : true, 
    xfbml : true 
});

FB.ui({
    method : 'feed',
    name : 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
    caption : 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
    description : ('Description'),
    link : 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
    picture : 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
}, function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post was not published.');
    }
});
};
```

This is what I have on my manifest.json that relates to Facebook:

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'",
```

What is happening is that the editPage.html page is opened, and on the header I actually have this:

```
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

So the SDK is there...I guess...but the console.log('lala') is never shown and I have no way to trigger fbAsyncInit. No errors are shown on the console neither.

I disabled all my other Chrome extensions to make sure Facebook wasn't disconected.

Well that's it, any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem.  Found a solution here:  http://brianmayer.com/2012/12/building-a-chrome-extension-that-connects-to-a-facebook-app/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please expand the content of the link in the answer itself, so that the answer doesn't get stale if the link gets broken. For more information, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers.